# Django - проверка наличия полей при наследовании

Tags: python, django

Добрый день!

Интересует вопрос, как красиво реализовать проверку наличия в классе B полей, необходимых для примиси A. Стандартная схема из абстрактных классов **abc** не работает, так как конфликтует с метаклассом моделей Django (который добавляет поля). Хотелось бы что-то аналогичное ей ...

Для примера, вот такой код:

```
class SocialPostMixin(models.Model):

    def work_with_social_networks(self, add_list):
        """
        реализует работу с социальными сетями,
        использует атрибуты Post
          .text
          .postimage_set
        """
        ...


class Post(SocialPostMixin, models.Model):
    text = models.TextField(verbose_name=_('Текст'), max_length=1950)


class PostImage(models.Model):
    file = ImageField(upload_to=get_post_photo_path)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

как реализовать проверку наличия text и postimage_set, аналогичную abc.ABCMeta?

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте модуль inspect.isclass

```
>>> import inspect
>>> class X(object):
...     pass
... 
>>> inspect.isclass(X)
True

>>> x = X()
>>> isinstance(x, X)
True
>>> y = 25
>>> isinstance(y, X)
False
```

Comment: ну это не решит задачу: если изменить названия нужных примеси методов, исключения вызовется не на этапе создания класса, а на этапе выполнения методов ... (т.е. не валидация в стиле abc).

Пока что перешёл на прокси-модель, хотябы PyCharm-валидаторы заработали